# TeamCity Build Agent on CloudFoundry?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, jetbrains-ide, cloud-foundry

Is it possible to deploy TeamCity build agents onto CloudFoundry?
Is there an OSS project/buildpack for doing something like this?
I'm very new to cloud foundry; how would someone go about creating one?

Comment: I google'd and found a Docker container.  You could try that, however it may require some escalated privileges.  If you're deploying your own Cloud Foundry you may be able to configure it to allow privileged containers.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta Thanks. I'm still new to cloud foundry and docker. The people I've spoken to about CF seem to dislike using docker with it. I'm trying to create a PoC for Cloud Foundry in my org; it would be a more difficult sell to my IT boss if I had to use docker as well, so I'm looking for a pure CloudFoundry solution to this.

Comment: Looks like it's a Java application, and I saw something about tomcat.  Are you familiar with how to get Java applications that you develop on your workstation running on Cloud Foundry?  Are you able to get a teamcity agent application running on your workstation?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. If you would like to run TeamCity agents on virtual machines, there is a good build-it support cloud providers in TeamCity. Two come out of the box: VMWare and AWS. If you need to replicate an environment/bluprint during your build process using CloudFoundry, there is programmatic API for this.